# CodeIgniter Tank Auth make user folder with him name upon registration

Tags: php

I found some similar question 1 year ago: [Codeigniter Tank Auth add folder upon registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10905736/codeigniter-tank-auth-add-folder-upon-registration)... but not with username included.
I tried to add username (of the registered person in that moment) in module, function create_user.This function create new folder with `$user_id` and `_` like: `1_` but without username of the registered person. I tried to include data `$username` from `$data` array, but hoplesss...

```
if($this->db->insert($this->table_name, $data)) { 
$user_id = $this->db->insert_id();
$name = $username;

    if(!is_dir(FCPATH."./uploads/".$user_id."_".$name)){
        mkdir(FCPATH."./uploads/".$user_id."_".$name , 0777);
    }
```

I know that `$data` array has username on 1. position for DB write purpose. I tried this possiblity: `$name = $username; $name = $data[0];` I found that the library, Tank_auth.php has function `get_username()`. It is for later purpose when the new user will log in... 
How can I get username from `$data` or DB, table users, cell username ?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$name = $data['username'];
```

in your code to get the name of the user.

From [CodeIgniter Active Record manual](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#insert), `$data` is an associative array which will have table field names as keys.

From [Tank Auth](http://konyukhov.com/soft/tank_auth/) it is clear that `users` table contains a field with the name `username` to store the user's name.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you Vanga. I was sure that I tried all the possibilities, but I done a mistake at this code.